# Plotting multiple lists of tuples using matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, tuples

I have formatted data such as this example:

```
datalist =  [[(u'2017-06-28', 12), (u'2017-06-29', 0), (u'2017-06-30', 17), (u'2017-06-26', 17), (u'2017-06-27', 8), (u'2017-07-02', 0), (u'2017-07-01', 2)], [(u'2017-06-28', 6), (u'2017-06-29', 3), (u'2017-06-30', 13), (u'2017-06-26', 12), (u'2017-06-27', 9), (u'2017-07-02', 1), (u'2017-07-01', 2)]]
```

which is basically a list of lists of tuples - ([[(date, value), …], [(date, value), …]]. I would like to plot this data such that dates will correspond x-axis labels and values will be heights of my bars for my bar chart. What is the best -or less time consuming way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should at least make an attempt first. A 3-liner approach would separate your tuples out into two lists representing x and y via 2 list comprehensions and then plot as it's shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a bar plot of the first element of your outermost list, you should get your values into lists using a simple list comprehension, but to convert the date values directly into `datetime` you can do something like the shown below. If you need the values for the second element, just change `datalist[0]` to `datalist[1]`.

```
import datetime
x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[0],"%Y-%m-%d") for tup in datalist[0]]
y = [tup[1] for tup in datalist[0]]
```

And then just call `plt.bar()`:

```
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To plot multiple bar charts with `datetime` one can do the following:

```
x1 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[0],"%Y-%m-%d") for tup in datalist[0]]
x2 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[0],"%Y-%m-%d") for tup in datalist[1]]
y1 = [tup[1] for tup in datalist[0]]
y2 = [tup[1] for tup in datalist[1]]

plt.bar(x1,y1,.1,color='blue')
plt.bar([i+datetime.timedelta(.1) for i in x2],y2,.1,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you don't know how many `bar` you'll need you just need to make the last shown code in a for loop, storing the data in a list of lists(so that, for example, x4 is xarr[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb1Oe.png)), something like this:

```
xarr = [x1,x2]
yarr = [y1,y2]

for i in range(len(datalist)):
    plt.bar([j+datetime.timedelta((i-1)*.1) for j in xarr[i]],yarr[i], width = .1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I might have not stated clearly in the post but what I am trying to do is plotting all the list of tuples in my list -showing all the pairs, for each list in the same plot. To be clearer, my 'datalist' has not a fixed length, and I should plot each list it has in the same graph as I said. Thank you very much for your quick answer though.

Comment: You would like something like this then? https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Yes, only difference is amount of lists I need to process is not fixed instead of being two

Comment: @OzanDogrultan Oh, I see, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @OzanDogrultan now having a look at the question, this is really tricky, because we to make it look good it would be necessary to do some adjustaments related to the entry data, I think.

Comment: @OzanDogrultan I edited the answer according to your needs, it should work but some fine-adjusting should be necessary depending on the amount of the data, please let me know if it answered you!

Comment: As you said, there is a tricky part of the problem but your answer is pretty much what I asked. Thank you!